# What is the required cracker to hack into NSA?

Tags: hacker-experience

I have a 35 version cracker and I don't seem to crack into NSA still I don't know if this a bug or I need a better cracker

Comment: [Check this out](https://wiki.hackerexperience.com/en:storyline?s[]=nsa#hacking_the_nsa) did something like this happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an 80.1+ cracker. They have an 80 hasher.